Latex longtable environment text going out of column
I am using longtable environment to create a table in latex. Here my text is going inside the column. means text is getting overlapped.
For repeating header in next pages I am using longtable environment. and I don't want to increase the column size.
Is there any way to do so.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=0.5cm,right=0.5cm,top=0cm,bottom=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multirow}


\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}

\begin{longtable}{|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{4cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{1.8cm}|p{1.8cm}|p{1.4cm}|p{1.4cm}|p{2.5cm}|}
    \hline
   \rule{0pt}{1.2\normalbaselineskip}\raggedright \textbf{Student UID} & \textbf{Roll Number} & \textbf{Student Name} & \textbf{Academic Year} & \textbf{Applicable Category} & \raggedright \textbf{Receipt Number} & \textbf{Deposit Amount Collected} & \raggedright \textbf{Refund Receipt Number} & \textbf{Refund Amount} & \textbf{Lapse Amount} & \textbf{Entered By} \\
    \hline
    \endhead
    
    \rule{0pt}{1.5\normalbaselineskip}fhjksxdf & dffdg40001 & \raggedright AAAA DDDDDD EEEEEEE & 2024-25 & \raggedright Government Scholarship & \raggedright JA8542152 & 50.0 &  &  & 50.0 & rggyty\_hhhhgfgfgdfgf \\
    \hline
    
\end{longtable}

\end{landscape}
\end{document}


rggyty\_hhhhgfgfgdfgf isn't a commonly known English word, so latex has some trouble breaking it across lines. You can help latex by manually indicating possible hyphenation points with \-:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=0.5cm,right=0.5cm,top=0cm,bottom=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multirow}


\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}

\begin{longtable}{|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{4cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{1.8cm}|p{1.8cm}|p{1.4cm}|p{1.4cm}|p{2.5cm}|}
    \hline
   \rule{0pt}{1.2\normalbaselineskip}\raggedright \textbf{Student UID} & \textbf{Roll Number} & \textbf{Student Name} & \textbf{Academic Year} & \textbf{Applicable Category} & \raggedright \textbf{Receipt Number} & \textbf{Deposit Amount Collected} & \raggedright \textbf{Refund Receipt Number} & \textbf{Refund Amount} & \textbf{Lapse Amount} & \textbf{Entered By} \\
    \hline
    \endhead
    
    \rule{0pt}{1.5\normalbaselineskip}fhjksxdf & dffdg40001 & \raggedright AAAA DDDDDD EEEEEEE & 2024-25 & \raggedright Government Scholarship & \raggedright JA8542152 & 50.0 &  &  & 50.0 & rggyty\_hhhh\-gfgfgdfgf \\
    \hline
    
\end{longtable}

\end{landscape}
\end{document}

